# adding a new div after another one

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a new div right after a div with the class of dtext01 but its not working.
Here is what the div looks like with the class `<div class="dtext01"></div>` and I would like the final code to look like this `<div class="dtext01"></div><div id="rewards">Testing!!!</div>`

Here is the code I have tried with no success.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var stickyNode = document.createElement("div");

stickyNode.innerHTML = 'Testing!!!';

stickyNode.id = "rewards";
var referenceNode = document.getElementByClass("dtext01");
referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(stickyNode, referenceNode);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `document.getElementByClass()`. There are [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) and [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelectorAll) which can be used for fetching elements by `className`, but they are not standard across browsers.

You can always import a cross browser `getElementsByClassName` from a reliable source, such as [this one](http://code.google.com/p/getelementsbyclassname/), or write your own - or just use IDs instead of classes if you have a choice.

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is [*document.getElementsByClassName*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) (note the plural on Elements). It is a fairly recent addition to the [*HTMLElement interface*](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#htmlelement), so you should test for it and provide a fallback if it isn't supported.

To append your div just after the first node returned, use:

```
var referenceNode;
if (document.getElementsByClassName) {
    referenceNode = document.getElementsByClassName("dtext01")[0];
} else {
    // fallback to some other function
}

// Make sure you got a node before trying to call methods on it
if (referenceNode) {
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(stickyNode, referenceNode);
}
```